# save() causing the creation of a new record when trying to update an existing record

Tags: python, django

So I have the following model:

```py
class Session(models.Model):
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    forgepass = models.ForeignKey(ForgeProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    programid = models.ForeignKey(TrainingProgram, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    program_day = models.IntegerField()
    hours = models.IntegerField()
    session_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        session_count = Session.objects.all().count()


        self.sessionid = 'S' + self.forgepass.forgepass + id_gen(session_count)


        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.sessionid, self.session_date)
```

When updating an existing record on the backend, a new record will be created with a new sessionid and the updated values instead, while keeping the old record. What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you each time generate a new primary key, and the primary key is how Django determines whether to create or update.

You thus should only assign a new id if there is no primary key generated, something like:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    sessionid = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    forgepass = models.ForeignKey(ForgeProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    programid = models.ForeignKey(TrainingProgram, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    program_day = models.IntegerField()
    hours = models.IntegerField()
    session_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.sessionid:
            session_count = Session.objects.all().count()
            self.sessionid = (
                'S' + self.forgepass.forgepass + id_gen(session_count)
            )
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.sessionid, self.session_date)
```

Now that in itself has a problem: if the `self.forgepass.forgepass` somehow changes, it will not change the primary key.

But in fact **formatting the primary key in any sort of shape is *not* a good idea**. You should consider primary keys as black-box objects: something that is perhaps a `str` or `int`, but that is a technical detail: not formatting these.

If you want to assign it a `sessionid`, you can just add a (unique) extra field, but *don't* use the primary key for this.

Another problem is that here saving an object will at least require three queries: one to get the number of items, one to get the `.forgepass` of `self.forgepass` and finally saving the object. This is even more problematic if you would do bulk creates for example with [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), since then [**`.save(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) is circumvented, so please *don't* add logic to the `.save()` handler.